# Why won't my simple gui compile in Dr Java? I get improper format?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button

not sure if it's my code, but I'm doubting it as it's from youtube. I've been trying to get code from youtube down to dissect it. At this point I'm getting the hang of writing my own simple guis with buttons; however, Dr Java  still seems to be angry with me. I would appreciate your help. I know it's not one of the best compilers out there, but it can't be this bad, so I'm thinking it might just be the outdated code from youtube? (Code below)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class guis {

  public static void main (String[] args) {


    JFrame frame = new Jframe("Test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);

  }

}
```

After you check it please tell me what you think is going on. By copy and paste the exact error I'm getting is

1 error found:
File: C:\Users[Leaving this invalid]\Downloads\guis.dj  [line: 5]
Error: This statement or expression is improperly formatted or not allowed in a class body

Thank you for helping me. Also if I made the error of putting it below public static void, I did a code earlier where it was all ABOVE and it still didn't work. Looking forward to your output!

Comment: There's only one problem with the code: You need to capitalize the F in `new JFrame("Test");` Other than that, it compiles and runs fine. That exception seems to be one particular to Dr Java. Its code parser thinks it's running into something that isn't legal Java code, but aside from the typo, your code is OK. Also, when reporting line numbers, show us the exact line of code as well. We can't see the line numbers in your IDE from where we are. Which line is line 5 exactly?

Comment: omg thank you so much, also I have no clue which is line 5 dr java does not number lines the way it appears for you is how it appears for me what you said was correct regardless though

Comment: *"dr java does not number lines the way it appears for you"* So add something like `// this is line 5!` at the line Dr Java indicates when you click on the error!